# redux redux-persist typescript cannot be named error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am currently learning typescript and ran into an error using react, redux-toolkit, redux-persist.

The issue is

```
Exported variable 'persistedRootReducer' has or is using name '$CombinedState' from external module "/Users/savanarkens/Private-Projects/tukui-os/node_modules/redux/index" but cannot be named.ts(4023)
```

I did find some resources on the internet, though those fixes did not work for my error.

The code triggering this error is

```js
export const history = createHashHistory();
const rootReducer = createRootReducer(history);
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

const persistedRootReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
export type PersistedRootState = ReturnType<typeof persistedRootReducer>;
```

Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post more of your files?  I just dealt with the same error, but I would need to see more of your code to find the problem.  Please include the import statements.  Also, are you mixing js and ts in your project?